# How Long Does 1 Multiplication Operation Take Between Two Doubles?

Tags: c#

I have a process I need to optimize and I was wondering how long a multiplication operation takes between two doubles.  If I can cut off 1000 of these, I want to know if it will actually make a difference in the overall performance of my process?

Comment: That depends on a lot of things specific to your environment. You should try it out on your setup.

Comment: Use a StopWatch and measure the timespan. That should give you a good indicator. Write the result to a CSV file over several iterations of this test and then graph it. It should give you a good indicator.

Comment: do you have any reason to believe that these operations are the bottleneck in your application?

Comment: 1000 multiplications will not result in anywhere near a noticeable speed increase, unless you are doing those 1000 multiplications 50,000+ times a second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is highly system specific.  On my system, it only takes a few milliseconds to do 10 million multiplication operations.  Removing 1000 is probably not going to be noticeable.

If you really want to optimize your routine, this isn't the best approach.  The better approach is to profile it, and find the bottleneck in your current implementation (which will likely not be what you expect).  Then look at that bottleneck, and try to come up with a better *algorithm*.  Focus on overall algorithms first, and optimize those.

If it's still too slow, then you can start trying to optimize the actual routine in the slower sections or the ones called many times, first.

The only effective means of profiling is to measure first (and after!).

Comment: Started measuring the times, and it seems that the graphing package I'm using has the biggest bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Intel CPU's do in the 10's of billions of floating point multiplies per second.  I wouldn't worry about 1000 if I were you.
[Intel doc](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/cs-023143.htm) showing FLOP performance of their CPUs

Comment: 20GFLOPS? I'd really like to see a source for this number! Even with vectorization and multiple cores I don't know how it could get that high.

Comment: yeah, sorry left an errant 'per core' in there.  Fixed

Comment: @Gabe added link to intel documentation for you

Comment: Sorry, but that documentation is specifying floating-point operations, not specifically multiplies. An Intel core with 128-bit SIMD registers can perform 2 double-precision multiplies per cycle per core. A 20GFLOPS CPU can only do 10 billion multiplications per second.

Comment: @Gabe Sorry if I have something incorrect.  You say 'an intel core...10 billion...'.  Wouldn't that mean a core 2(duo) would hit 20 GF?

Comment: Lucas: I just meant that when you see Intel's GFLOPS numbers, half of the GFLOPS are adds and the other half are multiplies. When it says a CPU is 20GFLOPS, that's not 20 billion multiplications; it's 10 billion adds and 10 billion multiplications.

Comment: ah, good old multiply-accumulate.  Ok, at least it's still the same order of magnitude ;)

Answer (score 2):

That entirely depends on the size of the factors. I can do single-digit multiplication (e.g. 7×9) in my head in a fraction of a second, whereas it would take me a few minutes to compute 365286×475201.

Answer (score 1):

this depends on various things like, the cpu you are using, the other processes currently running, what the jit does ...

the only reliable method to get an answer to this question is using a profiler and meassuring the effect of your optimization